# How to integrate specflow unit test with MTM test cases

Tags: tfs, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow, microsoft-test-manager

How to integrate specflow unit test with MTM test cases.

1) I have created the automated unit tests in specflow-C#-BDD style.

2) I already have manual test cases in MTM

3) I am connected to TFS and my project is checkedin.

I need to make sure the unit test methods (automation) are run against the manual test cases in the mtm from my local machine. I have referred various articles over the internet but unable to reach to a solution.  It was found that i need to create test agents , controllers and environment which i am unable to do.

Please guide me from here.

Comment: How do you do this without specflow?  If we know this we might be able to help you come up with a solution using the tests that specflow generates

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate any MS Test Unit Test with a test case.

If you are using Specflow you need to make sure that you implement using MS Test. This is fairly strait forwards and allows you to execute the automation in a test environment. In visual studio if you open your solution that contains the tests you can also open the test case and associate on the automation tab.

You then add your environment within which you want to run the tests to Lab Manager as a Standard Environment.

http://nakedalm.com/standard-environments-for-automated-deployment-and-testing/